# Transacciones en Genexus no realiza ABM

Tags: genexus

He creado una KB en genexus X evolution 2 con el patron k2btools.
El problema es el siguiente: tengo más de una transacción, al tratar de guardar, modificar o eliminar la pantalla del navegador queda en blanco, sin respuestas y los datos que he intentado de **ingresar/eliminar/modificar** no se han impactado a mi base de datos.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola Juan.  Fijate en la consola del navegador si muestra algún error.

Comment: A esta pregunta le falta información importante para poder ayudarte a resolverla: ¿cuál es tu código? ¿recibes algún error? ¿ocurre con todos los parámetros o sólo algunas veces?. Por favor completa el [tour] y lee [ask] y edita la pregunta.